# How to get a character walking in pygame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, character, helper

I would like to get my pygame character walking. I tried everything but it's not moving. The player().x is not moving. What can I try next?

````
import pygame
pygame.init()
WIDTH, HEIGHT = 1920, 1080
ground = (69, 30, 6)
main_menu_color = (0, 0, 0)
max_fps = 60
class player:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 100
        self.y = 300
        self.width = 224
        self.height = 224
        self.site = "Left"
        self.look = pygame.image.load('character/sprite_0.png')
    def tick(self):
        pass
    def walking(self):
        self.x = self.x + 10
        print(self.x)
def drawscreen(playerpos):
    screen.fill((69, 30, 6))
    screen.blit(player().look, (player().x, player().y))
    pygame.display.update()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("Zooombie!")
def main():
    playerpos = pygame.Rect(player().x, player().y , player().width, player().height)
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    run = "run"
    while run == "run":
        clock.tick(max_fps)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
        player().tick()
        player().walking()
        drawscreen(playerpos)```
````

Answer (score 1):

You're not creating a persistent instance of `player`:

```
p = player()
```

You should update this rather than an unnamed `player`.  For example:

```
def drawscreen(p):
    screen.fill((69, 30, 6))
    screen.blit(p.look, (p.x, p.y))
    pygame.display.update()

p.tick()
p.walking()
drawscreen(p)
```

Answer (score 1):

Read about [Classes](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html) and [Instance Objects](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#instance-objects).`player()` creates a new instance of the class `player`. So every time you call `player()`, a new player object is created. You must create an instance at the beginning of the program and use that instance throughout the program.
Also see [Style Guide for Python Code](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/). Class names should normally use the CapWords convention and variable names should be lower case. So the name of the class should be `Player` and the name of the instance object can be `player`.

```py
import pygame

pygame.init()
WIDTH, HEIGHT = 1920, 1080
ground = (69, 30, 6)
main_menu_color = (0, 0, 0)
max_fps = 60

class Player:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 100
        self.y = 300
        self.width = 224
        self.height = 224
        self.site = "Left"
        self.look = pygame.image.load('character/sprite_0.png')
    def tick(self):
        pass
    def walking(self):
        self.x = self.x + 10

def drawscreen(player):
    screen.fill((69, 30, 6))
    screen.blit(player.look, (player.x, player.y))
    pygame.display.update()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("Zooombie!")

def main():
    player = Player()
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    run = "run"
    while run == "run":
        clock.tick(max_fps)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = "end"
        player.tick()
        player.walking()
        drawscreen(player)

    pygame.quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some problems in your code related to how a class and its instantiated objects work. Look at the following code and try to run it:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
WIDTH, HEIGHT = 600, 480
ground = (69, 30, 6)
main_menu_color = (0, 0, 0)
max_fps = 60
class player:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 100
        self.y = 300
        self.width = 224
        self.height = 224
        self.site = "Left"
        self.look = pygame.image.load('character/sprite_0.png')
    def tick(self):
        pass
    def walking(self):
        self.x+= 10
        print(self.x)
def drawscreen(playerpos):
    screen.fill((69, 30, 6))
    screen.blit(pygame.image.load('character/sprite_0.png'), (playerpos.x, playerpos.y))
    pygame.display.update()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("Zooombie!")
def main():
    player1 = player()
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    run = "run"
    while run == "run":
        playerpos = pygame.Rect(player1.x, player1.y , player1.width, player1.height)
        clock.tick(max_fps)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
        player1.tick()
        player1.walking()
        drawscreen(playerpos)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Here are some things to note:

1. Class methods can not be used directly like that (in this case). You need to instantiate an object of the class like **player1 = player()**. This means you created an object **player1** from the class **player** that you created.
2. An object is not callable i.e. to access its properties you need to use the dot operator in Python. Like **player1.x** and so on.
3. Lastly, your drawscreen function contains the **screen.blit** function which takes in parameters source: Surface and dest: list of coordinates. I changed it to the correct parameters in this case. Your source parameter was a callable so was not throwing an error, but what it was returning, that was not the expected type required.

Hope this helps!